# What are the irreducible representations of a direct sum of Lie Algebras?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

If I have two semisimple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$, then I have read that the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$ are precisely the tensor products of the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$.  Why is this the case?

My question is two-fold.  First, if $V$ and $W$ are irreps of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}$ respectively, then why is $V \otimes W$ an irrep of $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$?  And second, if $U$ is an irrep of $\mathfrak{g} \oplus \mathfrak{h}$, then how can I decompose it into a tensor product $V \otimes W$ such that $V$, $W$ are irreps of $\mathfrak{g}$, $\mathfrak{h}$ respectively.

Comment: I looked at that question and it didn't seem to answer my question.  I'd like a proof that the two sets of representations are in bijection with each other

Comment: You should find this in Sepanski's book, which was mentioned in the answer.