# 2-dimensional irreducible representation of semisimple Lie algebras

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Suppose that 
$\mathfrak g$ has a $2$-dimensional irreducible representation.  How to show that 
$\mathfrak g$ splits as a direct sum $\mathfrak g_1\oplus\mathfrak g_2$ where 
$\mathfrak g_1\cong \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, it is a direct sum of simple ideals
$\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{g}_1\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathfrak{g}_s$.
By looking at the minimal dimension of a nontrivial irreducible representation of the simple Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}_i$, we see that the dimension can be $2$ only for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$, see [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=2ahUKEwjvzaa2rtXlAhWKzoUKHdwYCKQQFjADegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fhomepage.univie.ac.at%2FDietrich.Burde%2Fpapers%2Fburde_29_mu_reductive.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1rhryBjTa94GEiUCFBj8zw), the table on page $3$. Hence one of the factors equals $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb C)$. For the irreducible representations of direct sums of simple Lie algebras see here:

[What are the irreducible representations of a direct sum of Lie Algebras?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459965/what-are-the-irreducible-representations-of-a-direct-sum-of-lie-algebras?noredirect=1&lq=1)